# Axios HTTP call is always treated as succeed

Tags: javascript, http, axios

So I'm trying for multiple ways to get error response status from my axios HTTP call and something weird is happening.

```
        getData() {
            axios.get(`/api/article/getObserved.php`, axiosConfig)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log('success');
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log('error');
                    console.log(err.status);
                    console.log(err.response.status)
                });
        }
```

So I'm calling my getObserved endpoint and although it's returning `http_response_code(503);` it's going to `.then()` part because it console log 'success' string.

this is output from console:

> GET http://localhost/obiezaca/v2/api/article/getObserved.php 503 (Service Unavailable)
>
> success favouriteArticles.vue?31bd:83

I've done hundreds of calls like this and this `.catch` was always catching error even tho I'm not throwing exception like in other lenguages I would do. However I also tried like this:

```
        getData() {
            axios.get(`/api/article/getObserved.php`, axiosConfig)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log('success');
                    console.log(response);
                }, function (err) {
                    console.log('error');
                    console.log(err.status);
                    console.log(err.response.status);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log('error');
                    console.log(err.status);
                    console.log(err.response.status)
                });
        }
```

But it still doesn't console 'error' although I have this 503 bad request returned from my endpoint. Why?

---

I also would like to add that I dont think [my endpoint](https://pastebin.com/XAiiHPVd) is not working correctly because I was testing it with tests and manually by cURL and POSTMAN and everything was fine.

---

**Edit** since response is undefined when I don't get data from my endpoint and I need to handle only one error (there is data or not) I have just do something like this:

```
        getData() {
            axios.get(`/api/article/getObserved.php`, axiosConfig)
                .then(response => {
                    if(response) {
                        this.articles = response.data.records;
                    } else {
                        this.noFavourite = true;
                        this.articles = [];
                    }
                });
```

and it's working. I'll pray to not get into same issue with some call where I'll need to handle several different errors.

Comment: Can you show us what's in `axiosConfig`?

Comment: Sure but it's only exporting baseURL `export default { baseURL: 'http://localhost/obiezaca/v2' }` and I'm importing it just after opening script tags after axios: `import axios from 'axios';
    import axiosConfig from '../../../../../config/axios.conf.js';`.

Comment: Can you try changing the `/api/article/getObserved.php` to something like `/api/article/iKnowThisWillBeA404.php` and see if that causes the `.catch` to fire?

Comment: Axios do not handle Network error

Comment: It correctly fire `.catch` and `,function(err)` when I change URL to not existing one. What does it mean? @Abdeslem Charif it's not about network connection.

Comment: @BT101 can you test this `.catch(response => {           
            dispatch(authError(response.response.data.error));
          });` i didnt want to post it as answer because i didnt test it

Comment: It didn't help :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This issue was related to my httpInterceptor

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { store } from '../store/store';

export default function execute() {
    axios.interceptors.request.use(function(config) {
        const token = store.state.token;
        if(token) {
            config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
            //console.log(config);
            return config;
        } else {
            return config;
        }
    }, function(err) {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    });
    axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
        return response;
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err.response.status)
        return Promise.reject(err); // i didn't have this line before
    });
}
```

which wasn't returning promise on error response so after in promise of http call it somehow treated it as success. After adding `return Promise.reject(err);` inside my interceptor it's working fine

Comment: Super useful, I ran into exact exact same problem!

Comment: Worked for me as well, adding `return Promise.reject(err);` helped!